# C#: Manage a thread waiting queue

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've an event fired multiple times. Each firing spawn a thread that will process an input and these processing have to be sequential.

This is the code:

```
void TcpClient_DataRead(object sender, DataReadEventArgs e)
    {
        //the first stops the other ones
        this.parsingXML.WaitOne();
        //processing the string
        string pop = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(e.Data);
        BufferizeXML(pop);
        //restoring execution
        this.parsingXML.Set();
    }
```

Here I've tried to make the other thread wait and restore after the execution of the previous one has ended, but this solution restore all the waiting thread.

Is there a method for manage a queue of waiting thread?

Comment: Sounds like a lovely job for TPL DataFlow: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a typical case you can use the publish-consumer pattern. 
You can use a `Queue<T>` or `ConcurrentQueue<T>` to queue the events, and then have a single thread dequeuing and executing the actual handling. You just need a single thread since you said they need to be executed sequentially, this will avoid the time in creating threads. Just keep an eye to the fact that you must lock the queue access if you can't ( mostly because you are forced to use older version of the framework ) use the concurrent version.

Comment: +1, yeah ,and also avoid the thread micro-management that newbies always get wrong, and those with more experience never attempt.  Unfortunately, the OP seems to have read one of the many, apalling 'Introduction to Threads' books/sites that always seem to start with continually creating threads and waiting for them to terminate with join() or whatever.  As I have posted many times before, the authors of these should be tied to a stake, their books/printouts piled around and a torch applied.

Answer (score 0):

Start a task when application initialize, create concurrent queue, start data read task and bind event handler after it.

```
ConcurrentQueue<DataReadEventArgs> list;
Init()
{
   var list = new ConcurrentQueue<DataReadEventArgs>();
   Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>DataRead());
   OnTcpClientDataRead += TcpClient_DataRead;
}
```

// PUBLISHER

```
void TcpClient_DataRead(object sender, DataReadEventArgs e)
 {
    list.Enqueue(e);
}
```

An always running job which process BufferizeXml for all data in queue, if list is empty it takes pause of a second and continue again  //CONSUMER

```
void DataRead()
{
   while(true) 
   {
    if (list.Count ==0)
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    string pop;
    list.TryDequeue(out pop);
    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pop);
    BufferizeXML(pop);
   }
 }
```

You can put some variable and let the while loop check it for breaking the iteration.

Comment: What happens if the TcpClient_DataRead is accessed at the same time by 2 threads? Wont work in this case, you need to initialize it at the start.